There is a long gap before main.dart.js is loaded in Flutter web
I created a page for the admin with Flutter Web.
Later, I received reports that the page is slow to load, and I want to improve the page load speed.
While analyzing the Network tab, I noticed that there is a long gap before main.dart.js is loaded.
I want to reduce this gap, but what should I tweak?



